# PHP Add Total for every records

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm trying to create an excel report using PHP Excel. Generation of the report is done. However, I have an issue regarding tallying all the column and displaying them at the bottom of every record name

I already tried generating Reports and it's working perfectly, aside from the issue that there isn't any total record generated at every end of the distinct record

Here's my code for generating Excel file

```
  $ext = date('Y-m-d');


    $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $excel = $excel->load(FCPATH.'reports/dtr/LeaveReports.xlsx');
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', '');
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H2', '');
    $excelrow = 2;
    $getAllLeaves = $this->db->where('type', 'L')->where('date >=', $date_from)->where('date <=', $date_to)->order_by('employee_no, date')->get('employee_manual_dtr');
    // $data = $this->getPayrollDisbursement($id);
    // foreach ($data->result_array() as $row) {
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$excelrow, $row['employee_no']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$excelrow, $row['company_code']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$excelrow, $row['client']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$excelrow, $row['last_name']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$excelrow, $row['first_name']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$excelrow, $row['net_pay']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$excelrow, $row['disbursement']);
    //  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$excelrow, $row['account_number']);
    //  $excelrow++;
    // }

    $emp = null;
    $total = 0;
    $total_sl = 0;
    $total_vl = 0;
    $total_co = 0;

    foreach ($getAllLeaves->result_array() as $value) {
        $sl = null;
        $vl = null;
        $co = null;

        if($emp != null){
            if($emp != $value['employee_no']){

                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . $excelrow, "");
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . $excelrow, "Total");
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C' . $excelrow, $total);
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D' . $excelrow, $total_sl);
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E' . $excelrow, $total_vl);
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F' . $excelrow, $total_co);
                $total = 0;
                $total_sl = 0;
                $total_vl = 0;
                $total_co = 0;
            }
        }

        $leaveFile = $this->M_dtr->getEmployeeLeaveFile($value['date'], $value['employee_no']);
        if ($leaveFile->num_rows() > 0) {
            $leaveFile = $leaveFile->row();
            if ($leaveFile->code == 'SL') {
                $sl = 1;
                $total_sl += 1;
            } else if ($leaveFile->code == 'VL') {
                $vl = 1;
                $total_vl += 1;
            } else {
                $co = 1;
                $total_co += 1;
            }



        }
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . $excelrow, $value['employee_no']);
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . $excelrow, $this->M_global->getFullName($value['employee_no']));
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C' . $excelrow, $value['date']);
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D' . $excelrow, $total_sl);
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E' . $excelrow, $vl);
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F' . $excelrow, $co);
        $total +=1;
        $emp = $value['employee_no'];
        $excelrow++;

    }

    $filename='LeaveReports'.$ext.'.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel '); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I want to insert total in every end of the specific employee record

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, I would suggest to first sort the data. Store all data into array and get the count separately. 
eg.

```
$USER_ARRAY=>
    [
        2013-001 => [
            'user_log' => [
                [
                    Fullname => 'FOO1',
                    DATE => '2019-01-04',
                    SL => '1',
                    VL => '2',
                    VL => ''
                ],
                [
                    Fullname => 'FOO1',
                    DATE => '2019-01-09',
                    SL => '1',
                    VL => '2',
                    VL => ''
                ]
            ],
            'total_per_user' => [
                    TOTAL_LEAVES => '2',
                    X
                    X
                    X
            ]
        ],
        2013-002 => [
            'user_log' => [
                [
                    Fullname => 'FOO2',
                    DATE => '2019-01-14',
                    SL => '1',
                    VL => '2',
                    VL => ''
                ]
            ],
            'total_per_user' => [
                    TOTAL_LEAVES => '1',
                    X
                    X
                    X
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Once segregation done, start writing  Excel

```
Foreach($USER_ARRAY as $user_id => $user_tally){

        $col;
        $row;
        foreach($user_tally['user_log'] as $fields){

        }

        foreach($user_tally['total_per_user'] as $fields){

        }
}
```